# Proving conformality and univalency of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Investigate shapes described by the quadratic mapping function $z = f(\zeta) = a\zeta +b\zeta^2 $ from the unit disc $|\zeta| \leq 1$ to $D \subset \mathbb{C}$. Assuming $a,b ∈ \mathbb{R}$, can you determine for which values of these parameters the map is univalent (1-1) on the unit disc, and for which values it is conformal?

**My Approach**

Conformality:

We know that, the function, $f(\zeta)$, is conformal where $f'(\zeta) \neq 0.$ $$f'(\zeta) = a + 2b\zeta = 0 \implies \zeta = -\frac{a}{2b}$$
The function is conformal everywhere except $\zeta = -\frac{a}{2b}$.

Uni-valency: Let $\zeta_1, \zeta_2$ be any two arbitrary points in a unit disc($|\zeta|\leq1$) such that $f(\zeta_1)=f(\zeta_2).$
We need to prove $\zeta_1 = \zeta_2.$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\implies f(\zeta_1)=f(\zeta_2) \\
         & \implies a(\zeta_1 -\zeta_2)+b(\zeta_1 -\zeta_2)(\zeta_1 + \zeta_2) =0 \\
         & \implies (\zeta_1 - \zeta_2)[a+b(\zeta_1 + \zeta_2)]=0 \\
         & \implies \zeta_1 = \zeta_2 \text{ or } \zeta_1 + \zeta_2 = -\frac{a}{b}
        \end{split}
\end{equation}

We need to choose the points where $\zeta_1 + \zeta_2 \neq -\frac{a}{b}$. We know that $|\zeta_1| \leq 1 \text{ and } |\zeta_2| \leq 1.$  Therefore, $$|\Re{(\zeta_1 + \zeta_2)}| \leq 2 \implies \bigg|\frac{a}{b}\bigg|\leq 2.$$
So, for any $\bigg|\frac{a}{b}\bigg|> 2,$ $\zeta_1 + \zeta_2 \neq -\frac{a}{b} \text{ and } \zeta_1 = \zeta_2$. Therefore, $f$ is univalent whenever $\bigg|\frac{a}{2b}\bigg|> 1, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: According to the definition the mapping is conformal if $f'$ does not vanish in the domain. So $ |a|>2|b|.$ It seems that the same condition guarranties $1-1$ property.

Comment: Seems like I am on the right track @RyszardSzwarc.

Comment: It's correct if you want injectivity on the closed disc, while you can have equality (though of course $a\ne 0$ still) if you want injectivity in the open unit disc; also injectivity implies conformality in the analytic case